# url tag not finding existing 'google_login' view function of django-allauth

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-allauth

I have a simple HTML content point towards the Google Login, as below.

```
# foo.html

<a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'google_login' %}">Google Login</a>
```

This simple demo project ***was*** using `django==3.2.x` and `django-allauth==0.43.x`. Recently, I have upgraded packages to the latest versions, viz, `django==4.1.x` and `django-allauth==0.52.x`.

After the upgrade, I was getting the following error -

> Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have confirmed the `google_login` is present by executing the `reverse(...)` function from the shell.

```
In [1]: from django.urls import  reverse

In [2]: reverse("google_login")
Out[2]: '/accounts/google/login/'
```

#### Error traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:1234/

Django Version: 4.1.5
Python Version: 3.9.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'crispy_forms',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'drf_yasg',
 'django_extensions',
 'rest_framework',
 'drf_spectacular',
 'accounts',
 'pages',
 'polls',
 'extra',
 'attendance']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/jpg/work-dir/projects/-personal/generic-django-example/templates/_base.html, error at line 32
   Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   22 :         <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
   23 :     {% endblock %}
   24 : </head>
   25 : 
   26 : <body>
   27 : <main role="main">
   28 :     <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
   29 :         <h5 class="my-0 mr-md-auto font-weight-normal">
   30 :             <a href="{% url 'home' %}">DjangoX</a>
   31 :         </h5>
   32 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href=" {% url 'google_login' %} ">Google Login</a>
   33 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'polls-api:api-root' %}">Polls APIs</a>
   34 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'drf-yasg:schema-swagger-ui' %}">API Docs (drf-yasg)</a>
   35 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'drf-spectacular:swagger-ui' %}">API Docs (drf-spectacular)</a>
   36 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
   37 :         <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Admin</a>
   38 :         <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
   39 :             {% if user.is_authenticated %}
   40 :                 <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   41 :                     <li class="nav-item">
   42 :                         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userMenu"


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 220, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 114, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 92, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 62, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 111, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 111, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 472, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jpg/.local/share/virtualenvs/generic-django-example-Kc6WXfau/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'google_login' not found. 'google_login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What could be the issue? How can I fix it?

---

#### Update-1

```
# urls.py


from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("accounts/", include("allauth.urls")),
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("attendance/", include("attendance.urls")),
    path("gql/strawberry/", include("strawberry_gql.urls")),
    path("", include("pages.urls")),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path("__debug__/", include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

Comment: Where did you added all auth urls, in app or project.

Comment: in the root urls.py (ie `ROOT_URLCONF`)

Comment: Could you share

Comment: Updated the post with the `urls.py`

Comment: could you try with `{% provider_login_url "google" %}`, first register `{% load socialaccount %}`

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work (see the [traceback](https://pastebin.com/hB1PgD94))

Comment: Oh bro, I think error not line that you show, you changed code but again return error about google_login, so check where you write down google_login

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment

Comment: Could you share you html template detailed. You changed error code line, but error not changed, it means error was not in line that you show